# Given a word get the meaning using WordNet API

Tags: nlp, wordnet

I am currently using the [wordnet search](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn) to get the meaning of words. However, I have a really long list of words and thus, would like to see the possibility of automating it.

For example given the individual word `goat` I want to get the meaning of it provide by wordnet.

I see questions about getting root word, hyponyms etc, but I could not find a proper solution on how to retrieve the meaning given a word.

Please let me know the possible options of doing it!

Comment: Can you elaborate question?
What do you want exactly, meaning of an individual word or meaning of a word in a sentence?

Comment: @TilakPutta I meant the meaning of an individual word. edited the post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Here is how to get definition

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
syns = wordnet.synsets("goat")
print(syns[0].definition())
```

## Output

```
any of numerous agile ruminants related to sheep but having a beard and straight horns
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually change it like this to get all meanings. `for item in syns:
    print(item.definition())` Can you please tell me what syns mean? Why are there four definitions?

Comment: syns means synsets which means synonyms of the given word